# Global variables aren't updating

Tags: javascript

I've been puzzled over this for a day or two. I'm trying to create a timer, and I've extracted some of the code. I can't figure out why when I log the variable *minutes* or *seconds*, the value remains 0. It doesn't change although the variables are global variables. Many thanks!

```
let totalTime = 0;
let minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
let seconds = totalTime % 60;

function countTime() {
    return totalTime += 1; 
 }

 function startCount() {
    countInt = setInterval(countTime, 1000);
  }

startCount()

console.log(seconds); // Why does the output stay 0?
```

Comment: you're logging the counter when the script starts. The variable will be incremented 1 second later.

Comment: `console.log` is immediate and synchronous. It logs the value of the variable at the time it was called.

Comment: `countTime` only updates `totalTime`, it doesn't update `minutes` or `seconds`. They don't automatically update themselves based on the expressions used to assign them.

Comment: You have a mistaken idea of how variable assignments work in JavaScript. Assigning an expression to a variable doesn't make it an alias for that expression. The expression is evaluated, and its value is put into the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `countTime()` only runs after 1 second but the the console.log is running immediately.

Try this:

```
let totalTime = 0;
let minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
let seconds = totalTime % 60;

function countTime() {
    // This will run every second
    totalTime += 1;
    minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
    seconds = totalTime % 60;
    console.log(minutes, seconds); // here you log after it has been updated.
 }

 function startCount() {
    countInt = setInterval(countTime, 1000);
  }

startCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var totalTime = 0;
var minutes, seconds;

function startTimer(){
    let countInt = setInterval(() => {
        totalTime++;
    }, 1000);
}

function updateTimeData(){
    minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
    seconds = totalTime % 60;
}

startTimer();

setTimeout(() => {
    updateTimeData();

    console.log(seconds);
}, 5000);
```

The setTimeout is necessary if you want to get the right results. JavaScript is asynchronous, so the console.log in your code is being called instantly and doesn’t wait for the setInterval (because it is outside of the setInterval function).

In case you don’t know: 
setTimeout works just like setInterval, but only calls once